# Laravel Mailer queue with Redis showing error "The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object."

Tags: php, laravel

This is the complete error.

> **Illuminate\Mail\SendQueuedMailable::handle()**: The script tried to
>   execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please
>   ensure that the class definition "Security\Mail\WelcomeMail" of the
>   object you are trying to operate on was loaded before unserialize()
>   gets called or provide an autoloader to load the class definition in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/SendQueuedMailable.php

We are using Laravel 5.5. And executing the following code

```
Mail::to($customer)->queue(new WelcomeMail($customer));
```

The mailer is the default mailer that comes with laravel, but we're queueing jobs to redis. Customer is a User object. The WelcomeMail is the following

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class WelcomeMail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('security::emails.welcome');
    }
}
```

Comment: The `WelcomeMail` gets serialized when put into the queue, then deserialzed when the queue is being processed. Was anything changed to `WelcomeMail` between serializing and deserialing? Did you rename the class? Did you move the class? Did you change namespaces? Those things can break deserializing

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was my problem. It was more than one server (localhost, staging etc... ) had a queue listener on the same Redis instance.